# Angular 2 Soap Client with Angular CLI

Tags: angular, web-services, soap, soap-client

I'm trying to use a SOAP web service with Angular 2. I'm using Angular CLI. I've tried using this one https://github.com/autopulous/angular2-soap

but I get an error saying:

```
System.register is not supported by webpack.
```

Is there another service or way to use SOAP webservices?

Answer (score 0):

It maybe a little late but the solution is actually easy.
Just go to your `tsconfig.json` 
change

```
"module": "system"
```

to

```
"module": "CommonJS"
```

or

```
"module": "UMD"
```

If it is `system`, it means the bundle compiled by TypeScript will be in SystemJS format which is not a "standard" way for module loading in javascript. While "CommonJS" and "UMD" is more popular so they are supported by Webpack. The choose of all 3 is not critical in my opinion. All of them are doing the same job and basically provide the same features. You should be painless to switch to CommonJS or UMD.